# Mass matrix of a Tetra10 element

Tags: finite-element-method

How or where can I find the mass matrix of a 10 nodes tetraedrhal element for FEM computation? Every nodes has 3 dof (x,y,z) so that the element has 30 dof. The Stiffness Matrix is a 30x30 matrix and the Mass matrix should have the same dimensions

Comment: just fyi there is also [Scientific Computing SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)